# Can an MDM system (e.g. GOOD) report on iOS app usage?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, mobile-device-management

If a company uses an MDM system (like GOOD or MobileIron) to deploy apps to their iPads and iPhones does iOS provide the MDM system data about when the app is used, so it will show up in their usage reports?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Airwatch, Good, and MobileIron all utilize some form of app usage monitoring. For a taxonomy of enterprise MDM systems, and their features, reference [this link](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9238981/MDM_tools_Features_and_functions_compared), specifically under the Application Management subheading.

Comment: Thanks Dave. GOOD just told me that they don't do any reporting on non-GOOD apps (https://begood.good.com/thread/4852), so I guess their monitoring is limited to apps in their environment/sandbox. Unless you know otherwise?